# why the file in core data still there although i can delete object successfully in core data

Tags: ios, sqlite, uitableview, core-data, swift

i try to delete the row in tableview and delete the core data like this:

```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {

            context.deleteObject(sounds[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject)
            sounds.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            context.save(nil)
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)

        }
    }
```

with context = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate.managedObjectContext!
and sounds is my Array which store the objects in core data.

i can delete the row and delete the file in core data successfully. i can check it because after i delete the row, i re-run my app again and the data is really deleted and does not appear on my tableview. But when i check the documents folder of my app in simulator. I still saw that data with some sqlite file. Why the file still in that folder? and how can i delete that?

Comment: CoreData stores your information using sqlite as a database (usually).  When you delete rows, it deletes information **inside** the database but not the database itself.

Comment: @PhillipMills, that should be an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a problem, i didn't remove the file by my own. so i have to remove the data file before remove the information inside the data base:

```
    var baseString : String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    println("baseString: \(baseString)")


    var pathComponents = [baseString, sound.url]

    var fileManager:NSFileManager  = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    var fileURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPathComponents(pathComponents)!


    fileManager.removeItemAtURL(NSURL.fileURLWithPathComponents(pathComponents)!, error: nil)
```